# What is the name of this basic law of logic?

Tags: logic

Given any logical formulas $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. Then:

$$
(\alpha \lor \beta) \land (\neg \beta \lor \gamma) \models (\alpha \lor \gamma)
$$

Unlike for Modus Ponens and the chain rule, we were not given a name for this law.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a "basic" law.

Comment: @DavidH I'm not sure. Why not?

Comment: The name for this, when viewed as a rule of inference, is "resolution".  I would recommend http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic) but it seems to be particularly unclear now that I look at it.

Comment: @CarlMummert I agree that this can be seen as a resolution, but I was under the impression that this is an independent and more basic concept. Good chance I was wrong, though - `Resolution` would capture the idea pretty closely imo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we work with *classical logic*, this a a propositional logic [Hypothetical syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism) "in disguise".

In *classical logic* we have that $\lnot p \lor q$ is equivalent to : $p \rightarrow q$ is equivalent to and so that $p \lor q$ is equivalent to : $\lnot p \rightarrow q$.

So, your example :

> $ (\alpha \lor \beta) \land (\lnot \beta \lor \gamma) \vDash (\alpha \lor \gamma)$

can be rewritten as :

> $(\lnot \alpha \rightarrow \beta) \land (\beta \rightarrow \gamma) \vDash (\lnot \alpha \rightarrow \gamma)$.